# exec cos(x) freezes program if x not in [-9,9]

Tags: python, regex, exec

```
from math import *

def solution_handler(self, input):                                                                                                                                                                                        
    while re.search(r'(?<!\.)(\d+)(?!\.)(\d*)', input):
        rx = re.search(r'(?<!\.)(\d+)(?!\.)(\d*)', input)
        input = input[:rx.start()] + rx.group() + ".0" + input[rx.end():]
    exec "solution = " + input
    return solution
```

This is the code that I'm using to solve the equations entered into the calculator I'm working on. It seems to work fine most of the time, but if I try to enter a function (cos, sin, etc.) with a value outside of [-9,9], the program freezes.

What did I do wrong?

*Example strings:*

- `exec "solution = " + "6*cos(6)" -> solution = 5.761 ...`
- `exec "solution = " + "7/cos(8/2)" -> solution = -10.709 ...`
- `exec "solution = " + "sin(12) + 3" -> Freeze`
- `exec "solution = " + "abs(-50) / 2" -> Freeze`

It seems to be the case with any function that I try to use.

Comment: Can you show the string(s) which are being passed to `exec` when it fails?

Comment: use `sympy` module instead of `exec` for this.

Comment: Well, what could possibly freeze here? Apparently the `while` loop becomes a infinite loop on the problematic input. You'll have to figure out why yourself though ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your loop: remove the `exec` and it would still hang.  Try this instead:

```
from __future__ import division
from math import *
def solution_handler(self, input):
    return eval(input)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Obviously you got that the loop was supposed to find all integers and turn them into floats, but I never thought to import the future. :) Cheers!